# Horizontally center list items that have different background image widths

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble centering list items horizontally within a container div. I have tried to use display:inline on the li and li a but this did not help. I also tried text-align center on the ul and the li which did not give me results. My solution is almost there however if I remove the two arrow LI's from the HTML it breaks and looks like the second image posted here instead of automatically centering the social media icons. I have borders around everything right now for troubleshooting purposes.

Ideally, if I remove an arrow or a facebook list item, the others should continue to center within the container. I am a bit confused on how to achieve what I want after trying float and the display:inline-block and inline method and having little results. I was able to achieve what I want with plain text by using display:inline, however these need to be background images and the arrows have a different width than the social media icons. (could be turned into a sprite as well I suppose instead of individual ones)

HTML:

```
 <div id="socialbox">
    <ul id="social">
      <li id="leftarrow"><a></a></li>
      <li id="facebook"><a href=""></a></li>
      <li id="twitter"><a href=""></a></li>
      <li id="youtube"><a href=""></a></li>
      <li id="rightarrow"><a></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#socialbox {width:400px; border:1px solid black; margin:0 auto; margin-top:0px; }
#social{overflow:auto; border:1px solid blue;}
#social ul {list-style:none; margin:0 auto;}
#social li{float:left; margin-right:15px;border:1px solid red;}
#social li, #social a{height:53px;display:block;}

#leftarrow{width:30px; border:0px solid black; background:url('../img/leftarrow.png')no-repeat 0 0px;}
#leftarrow a:hover{background: url('../img/leftarrow-hover.png')no-repeat 0 0;}

#rightarrow{left:0px;width:30px; border:0px solid black;background:url('../img/rightarrow.png')no-repeat 0 0px;}
#rightarrow a:hover{background: url('../img/rightarrow-hover.png')no-repeat 0 0;}

#facebook{width:62px; border:0px solid black; background:url('../img/facebook.png') 0 0}
#facebook a:hover{background: url('../img/facebook-on.png') 0 0;}
```

The image below is what my soluton currently looks like, which it is actual 2 pixels on the left side to little, isntead of centered.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? The first image looks perfectly centered to my eyes.

Comment: When I remove the list item of right arrow and left arrow (shown in the second example) the 3 social media icons do not stay centered within the div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues, I can see

- You have a selector `#social ul`, which should be just `#social` or `ul`. Otherwise it doesn't apply to `<ul id="social">`
- `ul` is a block level element, so it extends to the whole width - as can be seen by the blue border - and `margin: auto` has no effect. For this to work, you can set a width, which encloses the children and adjust the `padding` accordingly

```css
#social {
    width: 240px;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6yCue/) for testing.

As an alternative, you can increase the margin of the leftmost child, e.g. `facebook`.

**Update**:

If you want to avoid setting the width, you can use @ajgiv's suggestion and add [`text-align: center`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/text-align) to the outer div `socialbox`. But then, you must also make `social` an inline element by setting [`display: inline-block`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/display)

```css
#socialbox {
    text-align: center;
}

#social {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
```

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AAfX8/1/)

Comment: Thanks. Interesting, when I add back in the left and right arrow it needed to be {overflow:auto; border:1px solid blue;
list-style:none; margin:0 auto; width: 350px;} on the UL. When the arrows aren't there, your example is perfect. I guess the set width's do matter—I was overlooking this. Thanks again!

Comment: @James Yes, you must adjust the width to fit the enclosed children. See updated answer for an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

does adding text-align:center to socialbox do anything?

Comment: No, when removing any list item that I have shown there it still doesn't stay centered. Very odd. I've looked at a few other stackoverflow pages as well within similar issues and copied code but still when removing an item it doesn't stay centered.